# draw path on map in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am using the [Route-Me](http://code.google.com/p/route-me/) library for the iPhone.  My problem is that i want to draw a path on the map for example.

I am in Dallas and i want to go new york then just i will put marker on these two places and path will be drawn between this two marker.

Can any body suggest me how this can be done.

If any other Map rather than RouteMe then also it's ok.

Answer (score 7):

Following code will draw path btween 2 points. (in your case you have to add all route points)

```
// Set map view center coordinate
CLLocationCoordinate2D center;
center.latitude = 47.582;
center.longitude = -122.333;
slideLocation = center;
[mapView.contents moveToLatLong:center];
[mapView.contents setZoom:17.0f];

// Add 2 markers(start/end)  and RMPath with 2 points
RMMarker *newMarker;
UIImage *startImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"marker-blue.png"];
UIImage *finishImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"marker-red.png"];
UIColor* routeColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:(27.0 /255) green:(88.0 /255) blue:(156.0 /255) alpha:0.75];
RMPath* routePath = [[RMPath alloc] initWithContents:mapView.contents];
[routePath setLineColor:routeColor];
[routePath setFillColor:routeColor];
[routePath setLineWidth:10.0f];
[routePath setDrawingMode:kCGPathStroke];
CLLocationCoordinate2D newLocation;
newLocation.latitude = 47.580;
newLocation.longitude = -122.333;   
[routePath addLineToLatLong:newLocation];
newLocation.latitude = 47.599;
newLocation.longitude = -122.333;   
[routePath addLineToLatLong:newLocation];
[[mapView.contents overlay] addSublayer:routePath];

newLocation.latitude = 47.580;
newLocation.longitude = -122.333;   
newMarker = [[RMMarker alloc] initWithUIImage:startImage anchorPoint:CGPointMake(0.5, 1.0)];
[mapView.contents.markerManager addMarker:newMarker AtLatLong:newLocation];
[newMarker release];
newMarker = nil;

newLocation.latitude = 47.599;
newLocation.longitude = -122.333;   
newMarker = [[RMMarker alloc] initWithUIImage:finishImage anchorPoint:CGPointMake(0.5, 1.0)];
[mapView.contents.markerManager addMarker:newMarker AtLatLong:newLocation];
[newMarker release];
newMarker = nil;
```

Answer (score 4):

Route-me has an `RMPath` class for this purpose. Have you played with it? If so, what did you do, what did and what didn't work?

Answer (score 3):

Route-Me how to draw a path on the map for example, not exactly but close.

Use RMPath to Draw a polygon on overlay layer

```
//polygonArray is a NSMutableArray of CLLocation
- (RMPath*)addLayerForPolygon:(NSMutableArray*)polygonArray toMap:(RMMapView*)map {
    RMPath* polygonPath = [[[RMPath alloc] initForMap:map] autorelease];
    [polygonPath setLineColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.5]];
    [polygonPath setFillColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.5]];
    [polygonPath setLineWidth:1];

    BOOL firstPoint = YES;
    for (CLLocation* loc in polygonArray) {
        if (firstPoint) {
            [polygonPath moveToLatLong:loc.coordinate];
            firstPoint = NO;
        } else {
            [polygonPath addLineToLatLong:loc.coordinate];
        } 
    }

    [polygonPath closePath];

    polygonPath.zPosition = -2.0f;

    NSMutableArray *sublayers = [[[[mapView contents] overlay] sublayers] mutableCopy];
    [sublayers insertObject:polygonPath atIndex:0];
    [[[mapView contents] overlay] setSublayers:sublayers];
    return polygonPath;
}
```

Note:

The latest RouteMe has addLineToCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate instead of addLineToLatLong.

This is newer one found in the MapTestBed in example in Route-me

```
- (RMMapLayer *)mapView:(RMMapView *)aMapView layerForAnnotation:(RMAnnotation *)annotation
{
    if ([annotation.annotationType isEqualToString:@"path"]) {
        RMPath *testPath = [[[RMPath alloc] initWithView:aMapView] autorelease];
        [testPath setLineColor:[annotation.userInfo objectForKey:@"lineColor"]];
        [testPath setFillColor:[annotation.userInfo objectForKey:@"fillColor"]];
        [testPath setLineWidth:[[annotation.userInfo objectForKey:@"lineWidth"] floatValue]];

        CGPathDrawingMode drawingMode = kCGPathStroke;
        if ([annotation.userInfo containsObject:@"pathDrawingMode"])
            drawingMode = [[annotation.userInfo objectForKey:@"pathDrawingMode"] intValue];
        [testPath setDrawingMode:drawingMode];

        if ([[annotation.userInfo objectForKey:@"closePath"] boolValue])
            [testPath closePath];

        for (CLLocation *location in [annotation.userInfo objectForKey:@"linePoints"])
        {
            [testPath addLineToCoordinate:location.coordinate];
        }

        return testPath;
    }
    if ([annotation.annotationType isEqualToString:@"marker"]) {
        return [[[RMMarker alloc] initWithUIImage:annotation.annotationIcon anchorPoint:annotation.anchorPoint] autorelease];
    }

    return nil;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I've not seen anything like this - I would only note that if people are voting you down because they think you are talking about the new SDK mapping features, to read your question again where you are talking about a third party library (still possibly a valid need since you can't do turn-by-turn directions with the official map SDK).